# jQuery validation of a label content without id or class

Tags: jquery

I need to validate this labels in form 'mainform', the label can't have id or class or name, and if the label content is 'Status' then remove the radio buttons with label content 'Active' and 'Inactive'. I have to do it this way, because the application were build like this, and go over 250 labels adding an id can't be an option.

HTML

```
<form class="mainForm" name="eform" id="eform" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="rowElem noborder">
        <label>Status:</label>
        <div class="formRight">
            <input type="radio" name="irstatus" id="irstatus1" value="A" checked="checked" />
            <label for="irstatus1">Active</label>
            <input type="radio" name="irstatus" id="irstatus2" value="I" />
            <label for="irstatus2">InActive</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: why can't u not have id?

Comment: I have tried this but I am lose i am not I jquery js expert $('.mainForm label').each(function() {
    if (this.--get label text--) != -1) {
        $(this).closest('--radio buton').find('label').text(--content--);
    }
});

Comment: Show us some effort from you, not just the html XD, anyway I think adding 250 labels if the forms are static is far better than scripting to patch up that flaw. Specially if you are not experienced with scripting. Actually I would do a script to regenerate all the HTML with the labels correctly tagged

Comment: yes I try to do it, the code is on the 3rd comment box, but I am stock with what I can validate, what I can access from a html with j query, if some body know a good reference to learn jquery pls.. I have books and videos.. but none as advance like this.

Comment: 2 questions, what do you mean by "I need to validate this labels ?", and are all the <label>Status:</label> followed by a form with the 2 radio buttons? because if so it would be easier to remove the following "formRight" instead of the two radio buttons, also removing the radio buttons will leave the 2 labels with nothing on their side

Comment: You can access practically everything in the html from jquery or javascript

Comment: but where i can learn this.. as i say i have books none with that type of info jeje all just basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) functions you can do something like this;

```
$('div.rowElem > label:contains(Status:)')
.next()
.find('label:contains(Active), label:contains(InActive)')
.prev()
.remove();
```

Comment: Where can i learn jquery and the access of elements and contents ? and validation?

Comment: jQuery has a really good documentation and there are plenty of tutorials, tips and tricks on the internet. With time and practice you can easily learn. it is a really intuitive framework

Comment: I am stock with what I can validate, what I can access from a html with j query, if some body know a good reference to learn jquery pls.. I have books and

Comment: Yes it work, the radio buttons are gone, but the text active and inactive, status still there.. :( .. but i think i can figure out

Comment: I just figure out how to remove the text, it was easy, but just because your help. Thanks A lot !!

Comment: @user2795789 glad it helped. you should upvote answers that were useful. most upvoted answers stay on top and others users with the same problem will read them in the future